# Merging two audio files in Android using FFMPEG

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg

I'm working on an application that takes two audio files, and merges them into the respected channels. The way they are being equalized are not as good as I had hoped, So I want to adjust the volume of each file during the mixing phase. I've seen a couple of examples online, like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/714879/simplify-ffmpeg-amerge-and-volume-customization), [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Commands-2), and `[this][3]`.. but none of them are working for me. Can someone direct me in the right direction with this? Much appreciation!

I am using this library to execute: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Here is my code  (EDIT)

```
String files = "-i " + mVoiceFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -i " + mBeatFile.getAbsolutePath();
String filter = "-filter_complex [0:a]volume=0.99[a1];[1:a]volume=0.3[a2][a1][a2]amerge=inputs=2,volume=1.3,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout]";
String output = "  -map [aout] -strict -2 \" + mRapFile.getAbsolutePath()";
String cmd = files+filter+output;`
```

enter code here

and here are my errors from running.

```
04-06 12:17:34.079 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: WARNING: linker: /data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
04-06 12:17:34.306 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
04-06 12:17:34.306 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
04-06 12:17:34.306 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
04-06 12:17:34.307 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
04-06 12:17:34.307 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
04-06 12:17:34.307 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
04-06 12:17:34.307 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
04-06 12:17:34.308 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
04-06 12:17:34.308 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
04-06 12:17:34.308 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
04-06 12:17:34.308 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
04-06 12:17:34.372 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/recording.m4a':
04-06 12:17:34.373 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Metadata:
04-06 12:17:34.373 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     major_brand     : mp42
04-06 12:17:34.373 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     minor_version   : 0
04-06 12:17:34.374 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     compatible_brands: isommp42
04-06 12:17:34.374 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     creation_time   : 2016-04-06 19:17:33
04-06 12:17:34.374 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Duration: 00:00:01.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 144 kb/s
04-06 12:17:34.375 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
04-06 12:17:34.375 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Metadata:
04-06 12:17:34.375 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:       creation_time   : 2016-04-06 19:17:33
04-06 12:17:34.375 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/beats/d3c37d60-ed50-4c00-b454-4e399a7858ff.m4a':
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Metadata:
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     major_brand     : mp42
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     minor_version   : 0
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     compatible_brands: mp42isom
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     creation_time   : 1993-11-24 14:46:42
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     encoder         : Max 0.9.1
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     iTunSMPB        : 00000000 00000840 000003c0 000000000035dc00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     date            : 2015
04-06 12:17:34.401 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Duration: 00:01:20.04, start: 0.047891, bitrate: 129 kb/s
04-06 12:17:34.402 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
04-06 12:17:34.402 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Metadata:
04-06 12:17:34.402 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:       creation_time   : 1993-11-24 14:46:42
04-06 12:17:34.404 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: [NULL @ 0xb5e4fc00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3[aout]'
04-06 12:17:34.404 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3[aout]: Invalid argument
04-06 12:17:34.407 30975-30975/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Status Failed: WARNING: linker: /data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
                                                                          ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                            built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                            configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                            libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
                                                                            libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
                                                                            libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
                                                                            libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
                                                                            libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
                                                                            libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
                                                                            libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
                                                                            libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
                                                                          Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/recording.m4a':
                                                                            Metadata:
                                                                              major_brand     : mp42
                                                                              minor_version   : 0
                                                                              compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                                              creation_time   : 2016-04-06 19:17:33
                                                                            Duration: 00:00:01.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 144 kb/s
                                                                              Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
                                                                              Metadata:
                                                                                creation_time   : 2016-04-06 19:17:33
                                                                                handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                                          Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/beats/d3c37d60-ed50-4c00-b454-4e399a7858ff.m4a':
                                                                            Metadata:
                                                                              major_brand     : mp42
                                                                              minor_version   : 0
                                                                              compatible_brands: mp42isom
                                                                              creation_time   : 1993-11-24 14:46:42
                                                                              encoder         : Max 0.9.1
                                                                              iTunSMPB        : 00000000 00000840 000003c0 000000000035dc00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
                                                                              date            : 2015
                                                                            Duration: 00:01:20.04, start: 0.047891, bitrate: 129 kb/s
                                                                              Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
                                                                              Metadata:
                                                                                creation_time   : 1993-11-24 14:46:42
                                                                          [NULL @ 0xb5e4fc00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3[aout]'
                                                                          [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3[aout]: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2):

The entire filter complex should be one string, with no spaces, or enclosed in quotes `"`, if there are. Right now, ffmpeg thinks the complex ends after the 2nd volume filter and is trying to parse the rest of the complex as an output token.

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, Thank you for bringing that to my attention. I adjusted my original code to fit your suggestions and am now getting a "No output pad can be associated to link label a1..  
Did I miss something else?

Comment: You need a semi-colon after the 2nd volume filter.

Comment: @Jeremy I'm trying to run your command exactly, but its giving error `Error splitting the argument list: Option not found` .. My command is `-i /storage/emulated/0/jd.m4a -i /storage/emulated/0/jd.m4a-filter_complex [0:a]volume=0.99[a1];[1:a]volume=0.3[a2];[a1][a2]amerge=inputs=2,volume=1.3,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout]  -map [aout] -strict -2 /storage/emulated/0/mergefile.m4a` .. Any help ?

Comment: It looks like you need a space after the second input I believe! If you notice my filter complex I have a space before my dash. Maybe that's it?

Answer (score 0):

add dependencies
**implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'**

```
public boolean mergeAudio(Context context, File[] voiceFile) {


    final boolean[] isSuccess = {false};
    File ffmpegFile = new File(getMusicFilename());
    if (ffmpegFile.exists()) {
        ffmpegFile.delete();
    }
    String s = "";
    String s_index = "";
    String fileSize = "n=" + voiceFile.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < voiceFile.length; i++) {

        s = s + "-i " + voiceFile[i].getPath() + " ";
        s_index = s_index + "[" + i + ":0]";

    }

    String str_cmd = s + "-filter_complex " + s_index + "concat=" + fileSize + ":v=0:a=1[out] -map [out] " + getMusicFilename();

    String[] cmd = str_cmd.split(" ");
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        Log.d("FFmpegNotException_", e.getMessage());
    }


    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.v("onProgress", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.v("onFailure", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                isSuccess[0] = true;
                Log.v("onSuccess", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.v("finsish", "finish");
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("NotException_", e.getMessage());
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    } finally {
        if (ffmpeg.isFFmpegCommandRunning()) {
            ffmpeg.killRunningProcesses();
        }
    }

    return isSuccess[0];

}

public static String getMusicFilename() {
    return "/sdcard/podmod/merged_audio.wav";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] ffCommand = (cmd).split(" ");
ffmpeg.execute(ffCommand, new ExecuteBinary.....
```

Make sure you do not have any other space in your file paths.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case this may help anyone else out in dealing with this, this is my finalized, working code.

```
  String files = "-i " + mVoiceFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -i " + mBeatFile.getAbsolutePath();
  String filter = " -filter_complex [0:a]volume=0.99[a1];[1:a]volume=0.3[a2];[a1][a2]amerge=inputs=2,volume=1.3,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout]";
  String output = "  -map [aout] -strict -2 " +mRapFile.getAbsolutePath();
  String cmd = files+filter+output;
```